# Pressing shaft into bore or bearing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Curious as to what extent a shaft/pin will will follow a bore when being pressed in. 
Considering fixturing for a project to hold a shaft straight, but most of what I have seen, the shaft will self align to an extent(as long as the angle is not too much). 
Is there anything out there that says you can expect a shaft to align with the bore as long as the pressing angle is not more than x?

Comment: One reason a chanfer is applied to the leading edge then things are set straight for pressing - you don’t pres pissed..

Comment: To expand a bit: the shaft will self-align to some extent.  It'll self-align better if it's chamfered, but only better.  It'll self-align worse for a really tight fit, or a flexible press.  If you start pressing with the thing cockeyed, or using the wrong press, you'll damage the shaft, the bore, or both.  Hence the comment by @SolarMike that you don't press pissed -- the more impatient you are, the longer it'll take to do the job and the more parts you'll throw away.